# Find number of sub-directories in each folder separately

Tags: python

I have a folder that holds a certain number of folders and they all contain a folder within a folder, I want to check the number of subdirectories in each of these folders. I tried using `os.walk` and adding +1 each time it comes across a folder. But this returns the sub-directory count of all the directories, I want them separately for each folder.

for eg, lets say I have folder A1 and A2.

```
A1: subfolder1 -(contains)-> subfolder2 
A2: subfolder1 -(contains)-> subfolder2 -(contains)-> subfolder3 -(contains)-> subfolder4
```

Right now my code returns 6 instead of 2 and 4.

```
def count_folders(path):
    count=0
    for dir in os.listdir(path):
        nDir = os.path.join(path,dir)
        if os.path.isdir(nDir):
           for dirs in os.walk(nDir):
               if os.path.isdir(dirs[0]):
                  count+=1
    print count
```

Comment: The result you want could be, perharps, a dictionary like this: {"A1": 2, "A2": 4} ?

Comment: @igordsm I made a mistake in my question, I've clarified that now.

Answer (score 0):

This works fine when I try it here:

```
def count_folders(path):
    count = 0
    for root, dirs, files in os.walk(pth):
        count += len(dirs)
    return count
```

To understand how this works try to print "root", "dirs" and "files" one by one.

[Documentation](https://docs.python.org/2/library/os.html)

[A short tutorial](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/python/os_walk.htm)

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you can comment out these three lines, that can prevent the `count` variable to count the number of 'subfolders of subfolder'.

```
import os
def count_folders(path):
    count=0
    for dir in os.listdir(path):
        nDir = os.path.join(path,dir)
        if os.path.isdir(nDir):
            count+=1
#            for dirs in os.walk(nDir):
#                if os.path.isdir(dirs[0]):
#                   count+=1
    print count
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are looking for the count of subdirs inside each subdir in `path` you can try this function:

```
def count_folders(path):
    count={}
    for dir in os.listdir(path):
        nDir = os.path.join(path,dir)
        if os.path.isdir(nDir):
           c = 0
           for d in os.listdir(nDir):
               if os.path.isdir(os.path.join(nDir, d)):
                  c+=1
           count[nDir] = c
    print count
```

It returns a dictionary with the count of subdirs inside each subdir of path.

Comment: I made a small mistake in the question, essentially what I'm trying to get is the length of the directory tree. Please see the edited question